# If not Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel then what?

Tags: .net, excel, ms-office

Ok, I have a problem with the **MSDN** documentation for the namespace **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**. It states in the documentation in **MSDN** that the code in this namespace is not intended to be used by ones application directly but it's code for supporting features in the **.NET Framework**.

Nowhere says what functionality this supports and what should we use to interact with **Excel** documents if not this. If you know what part of the **.NET Framework** they are implicitly talking about here, please, let me know. I've been searching for this for almost 4 months now.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think they mean the actual implementation.  It doesn't say the same thing if you look at the _Application interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.aspx

Comment: Correct, ApplicationClass is used internally. The OP should use _Application to access those members. See [here](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/visual-studio-30678.aspx) for a little more information.